# How can I redirect after an action is performed in my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, http-redirect

I have a form set up to take in date time value. This value will then be sent as a parameter into my controller method "bookingdate" where it will be compared with other dates in the bookings to ensure there is no double booking, using a do loop.

However when I submit the date form, rather than redirect to the next form where a user selects other details it throws me an error or redirects incorrectly.

Here is my controller

```
def bookingdate

  @bookings = Booking.all
  @bookings.each do |b|
    if b.startdatetime == params[:startdatetime]
      @musicians = Musician.where (["id != ?", b.musician_id])
    end
  end

  render :action => 'new'
end
```

Here is my routes

```
match '/bookdate', :to => 'bookings#bookingdate'
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `redirect_to` helper and pass route to where progress

```
def bookingdate

  @bookings = Booking.all
  @bookings.each do |b|
    if b.startdatetime == params[:startdatetime]
      @musicians = Musician.where (["id != ?", b.musician_id])
    end
  end

  redirect_to path_where_you_want_to_redirect
end
```

I guess you want to perform some checks, if user has correct filled form

```
def bookingdate

  @bookings = Booking.all
  @bookings.each do |b|
    if b.startdatetime == params[:startdatetime]
      @musicians = Musician.where (["id != ?", b.musician_id])
    end
  end
  if condition_successful
     redirect_to path_where_you_want_to_redirect
  else
     render :bookingdate
  end
end
```

Comment: Hey Nermin, thanks for the speedy reply. However, when the use selects the date on one form and presses submit, I want it to perform the do loop and then redirect to another form. When I have the route 'redirect_to bookings_new_path , it give me an undefined local variable/method error. Thoughts?

Comment: Do you even have `bookings_new_path`, run in console `rake routes` and check if route exists

Comment: I have  bookings/new yeah